# How to handle the complex integration of this function around a branch point

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I have this complex integral to which I don't know if it's possible to assign a value:

The integral is on a small circle around the origin. The function is $\frac{1}{(z-1)\sqrt{z}}$.

The fact is that $z=0$ is a branch point of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$ and I don't know how to manage it.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, the integral is along a contour which takes care of the $\,\sqrt{\,z\,}\,$-branch cut.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the integral over a "small circle" is a circle of radius $r$.  To evaluate the integral properly, you need to avoid the branch point at the origin.  In this case, it is common to create a branch cut along the negative real axis.  Along these lines, consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z} (z-1)} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of radius $0 \lt r \lt 1$ about the negative real axis, with an inner radius of $\epsilon$.  Thus, the contour integral is

$$\int_{\text{circle}} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z} (z-1)} + e^{i \pi} \int_r^{\epsilon} \frac{dx}{i \sqrt{x} (-x-1)}\\+ i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}\, e^{i \phi/2} (\epsilon \, e^{i \phi}-1)}+ e^{-i \pi} \int_{\epsilon}^r \frac{dx}{-i \sqrt{x} (-x-1)}$$

As $\epsilon \to 0$, the third integral vanishes.  Also, by Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero as there are no poles in the integrand.  Thus, we have for the integral about the circle,

$$\int_{\text{circle}} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z} (z-1)} = -2 i \int_0^r \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} (1+x)} = -4 i \int_0^{\sqrt{r}} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = -4 i \arctan{\sqrt{r}}$$

Comment: So cool Gordon thanks a lot for your answer that helps me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: With the last correction, this looks good (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the branch cut along the positive real axis and computing the integral along the counterclockwise circular path, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z}(z-1)}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ire^{i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}(re^{i\theta}-1)}\tag{1}\\
&=-i\sqrt{r}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta/2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{1-re^{i\theta}}\tag{2}\\
&=-2i\sqrt{r}\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{i\phi}\,\mathrm{d}\phi}{1-re^{i2\phi}}\tag{3}\\
&=-2i\sqrt{r}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\pi r^ke^{i(2k+1)\phi}\,\mathrm{d}\phi\tag{4}\\
&=-2i\sqrt{r}\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k\frac{2i}{2k+1}\tag{5}\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{r}^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\tag{6}\\
&=2\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{r}}{1-\sqrt{r}}\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $z=re^{i\theta}$
$(2)$: cancelling and factoring
$(3)$: $\theta=2\phi$
$(4)$: $\frac1{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k$
$(5)$: $\int_0^\pi e^{i(2k+1)\phi}\,\mathrm{d}\phi=\frac{2i}{2k+1}$
$(6)$: collecting and combining
$(7)$: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$

Comment: So Rob, just to clarify things for the OP and others who may be watching, we have apparently differing answers, but could this be the result of how we have defined our branch cuts?

Comment: @RonGordon: with the correction involving multiplying by $2$ instead of dividing by $2$, I think the only difference is the branch cut. Looking at $$-\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z}}=-2\sqrt{z}$$ I get $4\sqrt{r}$ on my contour and $-4i\sqrt{r}$ on yours, which matches each of our answers.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
I believe you want to compute
$${\mathscr I} \equiv
\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R
       \atop
       {\vphantom{\Huge A} \epsilon\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ 2\pi\ -\ \epsilon}}
{\dd z \over \root{z}\pars{z - 1}}\,,\qquad\qquad R < 1
$$

> The integration is 'closed' along a contour $\ds{\gamma}$ which takes care of the $\ds{\root{z}}$-branch cut and a 'small semi-circle' around the origin ( this one yields a zero contribution when its radius goes to zero ). Obviously, the integral over $\ds{\gamma}$ vanishes out. Then,
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\Large{\mathscr I}}&=
> -\int_{0}^{R}{x^{-1/2}\pars{\expo{\ic 0}}^{-1/2}\,\dd x \over x - 1}
> -\int_{R}^{0}{x^{-1/2}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic}}^{-1/2}\,\dd x \over x - 1}
> =-2\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{R}{x^{-1/2}\,\dd x \over x - 1}}^{\ds{x \equiv t^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{\root{R}}{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}}
> =2\int_{0}^{\root{R}}\pars{{1 \over 1 - t} + {1 \over 1 + t}}
> =\left.2\ln\pars{1 + t \over 1 - t}\right\vert_{0}^{\root{R}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large 2\ln\pars{1 + \root{R} \over 1 - \root{R}}}
> \end{align}